# How do I run VBScript in Python 3.11 without a external VBScript file?

Tags: python, if-statement, vbscript, textbox, return

So, I'm trying to make a Python file and I want it to run VBScript code without the use of an external vbs file, because I want it to return X witch is "Yes" or "No" so I can use it in If/Else statement and I *tried* to use VBScript conditional statements ([VBScript Conditional Statement: IF Else, ElseIF, Select Case Example](https://www.guru99.com/vbscript-conditional-statements.html)), but they didn't work.
The VBScript code:

```
X=MsgBox("Error while opening C:. Do you want to fix it?",0+16,"C:")

X=MsgBox("Unable to fix this error. Do you want to scan C:?",0+48,"C:")

X=MsgBox("Alert! Virus has been detected. Trying to delete this virus..",0+64,"Alert")

X=MsgBox("Unable to delete this virus, virus starting..",0+64,"Critical Error")

X=MsgBox("Virus is Activated",0+16,"Virus Activated")

X=MsgBox("Deleting System Files..",0+16,"File Deleition")

X=MsgBox("Virus is copying your passwords..",0+48,"Copying Passwords")

X=MsgBox("Please wait. Uploading your files to hack server. Do you want to stop it?",4+64,"File Transfer")

If X = "Yes" Then
    X=MsgBox("Cannot stop. File transfer Completed",0+16,"Completed")
    End If

X=MsgBox("Your C: is hacked",0+64,"Hacked")

X=MsgBox("Your C: is deleted. Take out your hard drive.",0+48,"Deleted")

X=MsgBox("This is not real, there is no virus, and nothing has happend to your C:. And DO NOT TAKE OUT THE HARD DRIVE WHILE THE COMPUTER IS ON! You Got PRANKED! I got this at this link >https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdV6wKo5o1A. Have a good day!",0+64,"You Got PRANKED!")
```

But the conditionals aren't working.

I was expecting that it say "Cannot stop. File transfer Completed." if I hit "Yes" on the previous box in an info box with title "Completed" but if I hit "No" it would not display it.
But, when I hit "Yes" it skipped the part in the "if" statement. I also want what the user selected.
I tried researching for ways to do it, and I came across *[that article](https://www.guru99.com/vbscript-conditional-statements.html)* but it didn't work.
So I resorted to [you guys](https://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

[MsgBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function) returns `vbYes` or `vbNo` in your scenario so you should check for one of those:

```
If X = vbYes Then
    Call MsgBox("Cannot stop. File transfer Completed", vbCritical, "Completed")
End If
```

See Return values in the [MsgBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function) function's page.

Comment: @user692942 Like many programming languages, VBScript is processed from _top to bottom_ therefore the `0+16` argument would not affect the `X = vbYes` condition. Instead it is the statement above it, `X=MsgBox("Please wait. Uploading your files to hack server. Do you want to stop it?",4+64,"File Transfer")` (see the code in the question) that sets `X` to either `vbYes` or `vbNo`.

Comment: Why bother returning `X` when it has nothing to return? Also, I've used VBScript for 20+ years so no need for the lesson. It's a pointless question that has been covered over and over again. There are far better examples already in the duplicate target.

Comment: @user692942 the question is about the `If` statement which is what my answer addresses.  Your first comment on this answer is incorrect and you should simply acknowledge that.